# Angularjs expression in ng-click not working in android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-ng-click

I am developing an android application using angularjs and ionic framework. It includes a one touch calling feature, ie a user can make the call on touching a number. I used `tel` in `html5` but my bad luck its not working for me. Here is the code.

```
//this won't work   
<a ng-click="window.open('tel:{{hotels.phone_no1}}', '_system')">{{hotels.phone_no1}}</a><br>
//this will work
<a ng-click="window.open('tel:0471-679900', '_system')">{{hotels.phone_no1}}</a><br>
```

When the number is directly  given it will work fine, but expression in `tel` not working.

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular? There's no `ng-click` in that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `ng-click` is not JavaScript, it's an Angular expression. You can do this by exposing `$window` on the scope, and rewrite as such:

```
<a ng-click="$window.open('tel:' + hotels.phone_no1, '_system')">{{hotels.phone_no1}}</a><br>
```

However, I recommend adding a method on the scope instead, so you can just do:

```
<a ng-click="callPhone(hotels.phone_no1)">{{hotels.phone_no1}}</a><br>
```

Comment: Working fine now,i choose your second method

Comment: Can you show how a website can open webpage when url passed as parameter like this `openWeb(url)`.I tried `$window.open(url, '_blank')` but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-click or ng-href instead.

```
<a ng-href="tel:{{someAngularVariable}}">{{someAngularVariable}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a few months old, but I ran into a related problem.  If you attempt to execute a tel: href and you're in an iframe and using google Chrome, you need to target the _parent.  IE, FF, SafariAndroid native, IoS  do not require this.